# How to download all subtitles from Opensubtitles.org in a specific language?

Tags: linux, wget

Excuse me if this post is not related to this forum, but I couldn't find any other place to ask my question. It would be appreciated if you introduce me a suitable place for this post.
By the way, I am trying to download all the subtitles from Opensubtitles.org in a specific language (say English) and find their translations in another language (say Arabic). I tried wget, but I couldn't download anything useful from this site. (I need .srt, .zip and .txt files)
Can everyone help me?

Bests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The download link is something like:

```
http://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/sub/4617044
```

Where 4617044 is the ID of the subtitle. You can use this URL with wget to download it, but it won't have the correct filename.

Alternatively, you can use the [XML-RPC api](http://trac.opensubtitles.org/projects/opensubtitles/wiki/XMLRPC) to search and download subtitles.

Comment: Ok,It works fine. But may I ask you if there is any existing code for doing this task (search through opensubtitles.org, and download all the subtitles in one language)?

Comment: @Hakim Could you please clarify how did you make it work? I'm trying "wget {link}" and it's downloading some html, not subtitles. I'm also trying to paste all headers and cookies from the actual browser and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 19):

Downloading everything individually will put an unnessesary load on their servers. Better use something like http://opus.lingfil.uu.se/OpenSubtitles.php

Comment: This is much larger collection (1,390,584 files compared to 20,400): http://opus.lingfil.uu.se/OpenSubtitles_v2.php

Comment: And here in the 2012 version: http://opus.lingfil.uu.se/OpenSubtitles2012.php . On the http://opus.lingfil.uu.se/ you can also find many other free corpus.

Comment: 2016 version: http://opus.lingfil.uu.se/OpenSubtitles2016.php with supporting paper by the authors Lison and Tiedemann: http://stp.lingfil.uu.se/~joerg/paper/opensubs2016.pdf

Comment: opus.lingfil.uu.se is down, so I used http://opus.nlpl.eu/

Comment: For 2018 in English: http://opus.nlpl.eu/download.php?f=OpenSubtitles2018/mono/OpenSubtitles2018.en.gz Look in http://opus.nlpl.eu/OpenSubtitles2018.php for others